# Javascript special key events for string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a string on javascript from key events which are sending by C++ backend by GetAsyncKeyState.

I need some advices for creating algoritm.

My current code is:

```
      if(event.data.keyPressed !== undefined && event.data.keyPressed !== null) {
        if (event.data.keyPressed === 8) {
          inputRef.current[refFriendly(event.data.input)].value = inputRef.current[refFriendly(event.data.input)].value.slice(0, -1)
        } else {
          inputRef.current[refFriendly(event.data.input)].value = inputRef.current[refFriendly(event.data.input)].value + String.fromCharCode(event.data.keyPressed).replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '')
        }
      }
```

But for example creating '_' char, i dont know how to do with my algoritm. Because you need to press 'shift' & '-' keys at the same time.

Also i had tried :

````
      inputRef.current[refFriendly(event.data.input)].value.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
          'key': String.fromCharCode(event.data.keyPressed),
          'keyCode': event.data.keyPressed
        }))
    ```
but input value doesnt changed.
````

Comment: Have a look into a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) documentation. There are properties like [`altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/altKey), [`shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey), [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) and [`metaKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey) which hint the active state of such modifiers at the time of the key event.

Comment: @PeterSeliger i tried to trigger keyboardevent with charcode for input reference. but input value doesnt change.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `event` as of the example code is not a Web-API `KeyboardEvent`? In case you want to sync/synthesize remote keyboard events via a backend into a frontend-client the backend needs to generate a format which provides all needed information in order to create a proper Web-API `KeyboardEvent`.

Comment: All the char codes from WINAPI are same as keyboardevent. The only thing that i want to sync is generating readable and editable string into input from them.

Comment: Maybe the OP considers providing a more precise description of the problem, preferably accompanied by more, but only relevant, example code and data.

Comment: btw ... triggering an (untrusted) self created `KeyboardEvent` from whatever kind of input control does neither write to nor change the state of such a control.